# Another page is not started from the beginning in Blazor

Tags: razor, navigation, blazor, mudblazor

I've got a problem with Blazor, probably something with routing. I'm using MudBlazor components and I can see a strange behavior. I've got the navigation menu (MudNavMenu) and when I'm choosing to go to another page, it redirects me successfully, however it's not redirecting to the beginning of the page - it's redirecting to the same moment as the last page.
So for example: You scrolled all the way down, Yoy were at the end of the page, then You choose to go to another page and this page is loaded at the end, not at the beginning.
I have no idea why is that (and I would like a new page to be loaded at the beginning of course). I tried with normal href, MudBlazor Href, hrefs/Hrefs with Id (#), code-behind NavigationManager with NavigateTo method. It behaves same for every solution.

MainLayout.razor:

```
<MudLayout>
    <MudAppBar Style="background-color: #FFFFFF">
        <MudImage Width=200 Src="images/svg/logo-blue.svg"></MudImage>
        <p class="title-text">Some Title</p>
        <MudSpacer />
        <MudIconButton Icon="@Icons.Material.Filled.Menu" Color="Color.Info" Edge="Edge.End" OnClick="@((e) => DrawerToggle())" />
    </MudAppBar>
    <MudDrawer @bind-Open="@_drawerOpen" Anchor="Anchor.Right">
        <NavMenuMud />
    </MudDrawer>
    <MudMainContent>
        <MudContainer MaxWidth="MaxWidth.Medium" Class="pt-5">
            @Body
        </MudContainer>
    </MudMainContent>
</MudLayout>

@code {
    bool _drawerOpen = false;

    void DrawerToggle()
    {
        _drawerOpen = !_drawerOpen;
    }
```

NavMenuMud.razor

```
<MudNavMenu Bordered="true" Rounded="true" Margin="Margin.Dense" Color="Color.Info" Class="pa-2">
    <MudText Typo="Typo.h6" Class="px-4">Navigation</MudText>
    <MudText Typo="Typo.caption" Class="px-4 mud-text-secondary">Click to navigate</MudText>
    <MudNavLink Href="/" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" Icon="@Icons.Rounded.Home">Main page</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavLink Href="/Example1" Match="NavLinkMatch.Prefix" Icon="@Icons.Rounded.Info">Example1</MudNavLink>
    <MudNavGroup Title="List" Icon="@Icons.Rounded.ListAlt">
        <MudNavLink Href="/Example2">Example2</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavLink Href="/Example3">Example3</MudNavLink>
        <MudNavGroup Title="Examples">
            <MudNavLink Href="/Examples/Example4">Example4</MudNavLink>
        </MudNavGroup>
    </MudNavGroup>
</MudNavMenu>
```

Beside these, I have some razor components with content of course (some MudTexts, MudPapers etc., nothing questionable).

Comment: Your 'pages' are yous different substitutes for @Body. Which comp is doing the scrolling? If it's the MudContainer  than that is the cause.

Comment: @HenkHolterman You're right, this is the one doing scrolling. Should I do it other way? Or, If it's okay, can I somehow fix it?

Comment: Set the MudContainer  to fixed and add a scrolling `<div>` (or MudContainer ) in the individual pages.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problem. A long search for a solution to this problem led me to change here, I didn't find an answer here, I started digging guides for redirecting to blazor wasm.

And I noticed that I didn't read the guides carefully, in general, the App.razor file contains the following standard code:

```
 <Found Context="routeData">
    <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
    <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
</Found>
```

From this code as a whole, it becomes clear that when switching to another page, the priority is towards the `<h1>` tag.

Just add the `<h1>` tag to the page and when you go to this page, you will be redirected to this tag

Comment: A comment was incorrectly posted as [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77874295/5211833) here: "Today component 'FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1"' not work.

See:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77557986/focusonnavigate-does-not-scroll-to-selector

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/52412"